# How to refresh sfGrid in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, syncfusion

I want to refresh sfGrid according to the query when I click radioButton. 
The grid displays fine when it first loads.
But when I call redraw() in editablePage, I get an empty sfGrid. 
I tried .View.Refresh() and Use onNavigateTo's parameter but it failed 
How to refresh sfGrid..?

UserinfoModel

```
public void ReDraw(string rb_cond)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(" SELECT A.USER_ID, A.USER_NM, A.USER_POS ,A.PERMISS ,A.CONST_DT ,A.MODIFY_DT ,A.REMARK ,C.SYS_NM ");
        sb.AppendLine(" FROM USER_INFO A ");
        sb.AppendLine(" LEFT OUTER JOIN CHARGE_PRJT B ON A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID ");
        sb.AppendLine(" LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS_INFO C ON C.SYS_ID = B.SYS_ID ");
        sb.AppendLine(" WHERE 1=1 ");

        if (rb_cond == "now")
        {
            sb.AppendLine(" AND A.USE_YN = 'Y' ");
        }
        else if (rb_cond == "del")
        {
            sb.AppendLine(" AND A.USE_YN = 'N' ");
        }

        //AppInstance.Ins.dbHelper.BeginTransaction();
        _dt = AppInstance.Ins.dbHelper.GetDataTable(sb.ToString(), false);

        SetDataSource(_dt);
    }
```

.

```
    public void SetDataSource(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (ItemsCollection != null)
            ItemsCollection.Clear();

        ObservableCollection<FunctionDataGridModel> result = new ObservableCollection<FunctionDataGridModel>();

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            FunctionDataGridModel rootModel = new FunctionDataGridModel();
            rootModel.id = dr["USER_ID"].ToString();
            rootModel.name = dr["USER_NM"].ToString();
            rootModel.group = dr["USER_POS"].ToString();
            rootModel.permiss = dr["PERMISS"].ToString();
            rootModel.project = dr["SYS_NM"].ToString();
            rootModel.startDT = dr["CONST_DT"].ToString();
            rootModel.endDt = dr["MODIFY_DT"].ToString();
            rootModel.remark = dr["REMARK"].ToString();

            rootModel.Item = rootModel;
            result.Add(rootModel);
            //AppInstance.Ins.dbHelper.Update(_dt);

        }
        this.ItemsCollection = result;

    }
```

EidtablePage

```
private void NowUser_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string con = "now";
        UserinfoModel model = (DataGridFrame.Content as Userinfo.userinfo01).DataContext as UserinfoModel;
        model.ReDraw(con);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that your requirement to change the ItemsSource of the grid when changing the Source property bound with ItemsSource property in SfDataGrid.

You can achieve this by implement the Underlying observable collection property with INotifyPropertyChanged. Please refer the below code snippet,

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private ObservableCollection<OrderInfo> _orders;

public ObservableCollection<OrderInfo> ItemsCollection
{
    get { return _orders; }
    set
    {
        _orders = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ItemsCollection");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}


public ViewModel()
{
    _orders = new ObservableCollection<OrderInfo>();
}
}
```

Comment: when i add "new ObservableCollection<OrderInfo>();" in constructor, it show empty grid